# How to delete a row without reference to the DOM node

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

My web app receives a websocket instruction from the server to delete a specific row. The row may or may not be in the DOM (due to delayed render) but it does appear in the `data()` array. How can I delete it using JavaScript? The `row().remove()` command seems to need a DOM node and the `data().splice(index, 1)` function does not seem to delete anything.

Comment: Row of **what**? Connected to the array **how**?  What type of binding (if any)?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting on my question... much better, I haven't posted here before. Very quick response... awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the developer, Allan Jardine. He pointed out that the row() method can accept a variety of arguments to select a row http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

I can use the index number itself as an argument, ie. row(index). I tried it out and it worked perfectly.

Thanks Allan!

Answer (score -1):

When you add a row to the dom, you can set an attribute, for example `data-index`, to the index of the row in the data array. Then you can later find the dom row associated with some array entry by looking for an element with a matching `data-index`.